Restrict R functions for an exam
An unusual question: What is the simplest way to restrict R to certain functions for an exam? For instance, in our use case we would like students to use functions for distributions, but not other functions. So calls to qt, dt, pt, rt (an so on) are allowed, but not other functions.
We use the safe exam browser, so are able to call a specific version of R or use a specific startup file (.Rprofile).

Detaching the "base" package from the search path is not allowed, so good luck with that!

I think this is probably impossible to do securely in a language like R which allows computing on the language. I am tempted to come up with a suggestion just to give others some fun proving how easy it is to hack it. One thing which might make more sense is to log all code entered and let them know that you're doing this. Whether this would work depends on how easy it would be to detect malfeasance in the logs. What are you actually worried that they might do?

Frame challenge:  award marks based on the technique used rather than the answer obtained.  For example, instead of "Calculate the mean of 1, 2 and 3" ask "Using only basic arithmetic operators, demonstrate that the mean of 1, 2 and 3 is 2".

@SamR: regarding worries -> we want them to learn how to use R for finding specific values of sampling distributions like every normal person would do instead of looking them up in statistical tables. Otherwise they should perform calculations by hand or use the calculator, not R.

@Limey: frame challenge means automatic scoring is not possible; we could ask for the actual command in R, but this would also be complicated to score (typos, different ways of doing the same thing).

Let the students write scripts, which can reproduce their answers and check the scripts for forbidden functions.

I don't deny there are competing objectives here, as there are with any real life problem, but if "automatic scoring" is mandatory, then I think that should be part of the problem statement.  And whilst I sympathise with the quandary, I personally find it disappointing that ease of marking appears to be more important than assessment of understanding.

The following is a rough outline. I would never recommend this as a security-hardened sandbox: there may be subtle ways to break out of it, and I would at least work on it for a few days and request feedback from multiple sources before having any confidence in it.
But as a toy sandbox for an exam it may be good enough.
It essentially enforces a list of allowed functions by masking all other functions that are provided by the core R packages. This is in contrast to using a blocklist, since the latter will basically be guaranteed to always miss something.
However, out of laziness the following uses a hybrid approach rather than a pure allowlist. This is because we need to allow most primitive R functions, otherwise the console would be completely broken. We therefore maintain a (rather small) blocklist of primitive functions and allow all other primitives. But we block all the rest (i.e. non-primitive functions).
To block functions globally, we insert a “firewall” environment into the environment search path, which will be hit before any of the masked, attached environments. And since we mask all functions/operators that could be used to circumvent the usual name lookup rules, users (hopefully) aren’t able to circumvent this firewall.
One last thing is that this code needs to be executed after all core R packages have been attached, which is done by base::.First.sys(). Unfortunately R doesn’t provide a customisation hook that we could execute at this point. But we can override base::.First.sys().
Put the following into the site or user profile:
local({
  # We need to allow most primitives; so we take a (dangerous!) shortcut of allowing
  # them all, and then selectively removing (potentially) dangerous functions from them.
  primitives = function () {
    fun_names = utils::lsf.str(baseenv())
    Filter(\(x) is.primitive(get(x, baseenv())), fun_names)
  }

  block_list = c(
    '::',
    ':::',
    'as.environment',
    'browser',
    'baseenv',
    'emptyenv',
    'environment<-',
    'Exec',
    'globalenv',
    'lazyLoadDBfetch',
    'on.exit',
    'pos.to.env'
  )

  allow_list = c(
    # Put explicitly allowed stuff here!
    'qt', 'dt', 'pt', 'rt',
    'print',
    'q', 'quit',
    setdiff(primitives(), block_list)
  )

  stop = stop
  forbidden = function (...) stop('Forbidden')

  # The subsequent logic has to happen after the core packages are attached — i.e. after
  # `.First.sys()` is run. Since there is no suitable hook, we override the latter:

  .First.sys = .First.sys

  first_sys = function () {
    .First.sys()

    core_packages = sub('package:', '', search()[startsWith(search(), 'package:')])
    all_exported_functions = unlist(lapply(core_packages, \(pkg) getNamespaceExports(pkg)))
    forbidden_names = setdiff(all_exported_functions, allow_list)

    # Eagerly load all names, otherwise they will not be able to be loaded later on.
    lapply(allow_list, \(name) get(name))

    forbidden_list = stats::setNames(
      lapply(forbidden_names, \(.) forbidden),
      forbidden_names
    )

    # ‘compiler’ needs special handling.

    eapply(loadNamespace('compiler'), force, all.names = TRUE)

    `:::` = `:::`
    match_call = match.call
    eval = eval
    getNamespace = getNamespace
    ..getNamespace = ..getNamespace

    forbidden_list$`:::` = function (name, value) {
      if (as.character(substitute(name)) == 'compiler') {
        call = match_call()
        call[[1L]] = `:::`
        eval(call)
      } else {
        stop('Forbidden')
      }
    }

    # Allow calling this only once; this is required by the R interpreter, but we can
    # disable subsequent calls by the user.
    first_call = TRUE
    self = environment()

    forbidden_list$getNamespace = function (name) {
      if (name == 'compiler' && first_call) {
        self$first_call = FALSE
        getNamespace(name)
      } else {
        stop('Forbidden')
      }
    }

    list2env(
      forbidden_list,
      envir = attach(NULL, name = 'blocked')
    )
  }

  unlockBinding('.First.sys', baseenv())
  assign('.First.sys', first_sys, envir = baseenv())
})

Some more caveats:

If the user is able to control the session start, the above won’t work. This includes quitting the R session and starting a new session from the shell, as well as hitting Ctrl-C while R is starting, to abort execution of the profile code.
The above disables debugging/tracing functions and error handling customisation (which can be done via options() and possibly via Sys.setenv()), but it’s possible that I overlooked some clever way of breaking into the scope of a called function. If that ever happens, it’s game over: at that point the user can freely roam around “behind” the firewall environment, and therefore call any functions they desire.
Adding functions to the allow_list requires care! Adding the wrong function will completely circumvent the block. For example, allowing as.environment() may seem innocuous. But as.environment(3) gives the user access to the search path beyond the firewall, and thus breaks the sandbox.
The above causes an (innocuous, as far as I can tell) error message at startup. I’m sure this can be avoided, but it requires digging through the R startup source code, to figure out where this is coming from.
Auto-completion isn’t working, since that is implemented via function calls that are blocked. It could be reenabled with some extra work.
I have only tested this directly in native the R terminal. It’s possible that other terminal shells for R work slightly differently and break the sandbox (or lead to other issues).
The above code contains an exception to allow loading the ‘compiler’ package, which is required by the R interpreter. Unfortunately this punches a gaping hole into our firewall, since that package allows lots of shenanigans. I am almost certain that this could be exploited. A better (i.e. non-proof-of-concept) implementation would tighten the code further to ensure that getNamespace('compiler') can only be called by the R interpreter, not by the user. This is “left as an exercise to the reader”.


Thanks for the hint re compiler. Looks like it can be circumvented by creating a do.call() equivalent with docall <- \(what, args) Exec(as.call(c(list(substitute(what)), args)), pos.to.env(3)) that lets you run various functions. Then you can do docall(writeLines, list("system('R --vanilla')", "./payload")); `:::`(compiler, "cmpfile")("./payload"); `:::`(compiler, "loadcmp")("./payload.Rc", envir = pos.to.env(3)) to open a vanilla R session. Or other mischief with functions like as.environment(). Do you need to allow Exec() and pos.to.env? It would be much harder without them.

@SamR I missed pos.to.env. But where is Exec coming from?

Which R version are you using? Exec() was introduced in 4.4 as a friend of Tailcall() and is returned by your primitives() function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Tailcall.html

@SamR Ah! I am still on 4.3 for most purposes. Yes, that one definitely needs to go on the block list.

FYI if yo have access to pos.to.env() you don’t need ‘compiler’ or Exec() at all: pos.to.env(10L)$detach(2L) is all that’s required (if other default packages are loaded this requires some probing for the position of the ‘base’ package environment). Now I’m not sure whether you could cause mischief without that function, with only Exec().

Oh that's easier - I didn't know how to detach an environment with pos.to.env() - that doesn't seem to be in the docs. I haven't worked out a way to cause trouble with just Exec() or compiler without access to another environment. But I am ever discovering that there are many strange quirks of R that I don't know about, which is why I didn't feel confident about any approach. Though this does seem to be much more secure than I expected was possible. Nice one.

I would recommend not trying to whitelist functions. Firstly, R allows direct manipulation of language objects which would make it possible to circumvent any approach that I can think of. Secondly, R has no concept of permissions in the way that an operating system does, and I can't see any way to prevent students from undoing whatever you put in place.
Logging will not work either
A more practical approach might be to log everything students do. Initially, I thought this might be a solution. However, in writing this answer, I realised it will not so I thought I would explain why. Firstly, if you log to a local file then students will need to have write access to the file, which means that they may be able to delete or amend logs. So instead you could send the logs to a web server. Let's do it in R here for simplicity.
logging_server.R
#* Log received messages
#* @post /log
function(entry, username, nodename) {
    log_file <- sprintf(
        "r_command_log-%s-%s.txt", username, nodename
    )
    cat(entry, file = log_file, append = TRUE, sep = "\n")
    list(status = "success")
}

run_server.R
In this case I'll run it on localhost, i.e. the same machine that I am running the R code on, but in reality you would want an actual server.
library(plumber)
pr <- plumb("logging_server.R")
pr$run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8000)

You can then run this from the terminal:
Rscript run_server.R

.Rprofile
Add then add the following to your .Rprofile.
log_command <- function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    log_entry <- paste0(
        "[", Sys.time(), "]: ",
        deparse(expr)
    )

    httr::POST(
        url = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/log",
        body = list(
            entry = log_entry,
            username = Sys.info()["user"],
            nodename = Sys.info()["nodename"]
        ),
        encode = "form"
    )

    TRUE
}
addTaskCallback(log_command)

Example R script
Let's say I run this:
qt(0.15, 5, lower.tail = FALSE)
message("I am cheating now!")

A file is created called r_command_log-samr-samdesktop.txt which contains:
[2024-10-08 11:19:36.343392]: addTaskCallback(log_command)
[2024-10-08 11:19:37.046776]: qt(0.15, 5, lower.tail = FALSE)
[2024-10-08 11:19:37.427953]: message("I am cheating now!")

Why this will not work
There are several caveats that occur to me:

A user could do removeTaskCallback() - I don't think this is a huge problem on its own as it should be logged and would be pretty clear evidence of cheating.
A user could disconnect from the network. This is a much bigger problem and could be a deal breaker, depending on your environment. Is it possible for your users to do this either physically or through software? If so they could disconnect, remove the callback, reconnect, do what they need to do, disconnect, re-create the callback and add some dummy code that looks innocent.
What happens if the log is not created for some reason? It may be evidence that there has been tampering but it is not definitive.
This is the big one. If a function exits with an error, there is no callback. For example, stop("I am cheating without a callback!") does not create an entry in the log. This means someone could this:

{
    message("forbidden function")
    stop("I am cheating without a callback!")
}

As the block exited with an error, does not create an entry in the log. It might be possible to add a custom error handler by setting options(error) but I think this could probably be circumvented by manipulating the stack frame so R does not realise what the last error actually was.
So I think the principle of this answer is that it is unlikely to be possible to achieve your goal securely through whitelisting or logging.

I don’t see how a carefully curated whitelist (as opposed to a blacklist) could be circumvented. You just need to avoid adding elements that allow escaping local scope or evaluation. (such as rm(), assign(), <<-). You could even make this work (albeit with difficulties) in .GlobalEnv (rather than a sandboxed environment) by overriding all blocked functions with stubs.

@KonradRudolph I don't feel confident that I could implement a whitelist in R that would be secure but if you do I'd enjoy having a go at breaking it.

I really don’t have time for this unfortunately, but I couldn’t resist at least taking a stab at it: https://gist.github.com/klmr/3ed0ef245aa98ad0f1300f24632f2bc8 — Caveats: the shortcut I took to create the allow list from the primitives might backfire (as indicated by the comment). And there might be some exploit possible by provoking certain errors. But since both options() and Sys.setenv() (as well as the debugging functions) are also blocked, I currently can’t think of a way to exploit this.

… and the current code still shows a message “Error in getNamespace("utils") : Forbidden” at startup. I’m sure it should be possible to suppress this, but I can’t waste more time on this now. :-(

@KonradRudolph this is pretty awesome. I also have very limited time right now but I can't see any straightforward way to break out of this. I can see the potential for some convoluted ways - something along the lines of Exec(call("browser"), pos.to.env(1)) though that doesn't work - might be worth adding those to the block_list though. Perhaps you should post as an answer? I doubt many people have seen your comment and it would be interesting to see what others think. Only caveat is that (this is kind of cheating) as it stands I can q() and ignore .Rprofile i.e. R --vanilla

Yes, this assumes that the user cannot control the session (i.e. that the session is already running, and that the user cannot drop out of it into a shell). Otherwise it will be very hard to control anything.

@KonradRudolph I have just realised I can't actually run qt() in this environment. The first time I run qt(0.15, 5, lower.tail = FALSE) I get Error in ..getNamespace(c("stats", "4.4.0"), "<unknown>") : Forbidden. The second time I get a different error Error in .signalSimpleWarning("restarting interrupted promise evaluation",  : Forbidden. And then third and subsequent times Error: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?...

The user cannot control the session in our setup. They can only start R and we can provide a custom .Rprofile for that. We use safe exam browser so the user cannot just do whatever they please; calling R --vanilla will not be possible. I will try out your approach, thx a lot!

Oh, too bad. But I guess there should be some workaround, e.g. I could redefine those functions, right?

@SamR Ah damn. Lazy-loading, I guess? This clearly requires some more work…

@SamR Ah yes, that was it. Luckily easy to fix.

It greatly depends on what you want to restrict. As @Edward said, you can't detach the base package. I see several options.
You could override the undesired functions (e.g. mean <- function(x, ...) { stop("Do it yourself!") }, but they could just be rm()d, or the environment in which they are defined could be detached.
Or you could (?) detach the stats package.  But then your student's might just re-attach it.  So you'd need to actually uninstall a core package -- and I'm pretty sure that voids your warranty.  Of course they can just reinstall stats, so you'd also need to disable install.packages() or uninstall utils, where install.packages() resides.  However, if you want to keep some of the functions in stats you would need to re-implement them yourself.  You could copy the originals from the stats package, but most of them are implmented in C, so you'd need to deal with that (recompiling, etc), plus all the dependencies, included unexported functions inside stats.
I think it is clear by now that this is not simple or tamper-proof at all.  So I suggest either finding a tool other than R, or building an exam that can't be "cheated" by using the whole stats package.
